# How to retrieve the JSON results array in parse.com using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parse-platform

`AddProduct` is the class Name. I get the id of object but i can't get keys and values.

```
query.find({
                success:function(results)
                { 
                console.log(results.length);
                for(i=0;i<results.length;i++)
                {
                  object=results[i];
                console.log(object.id);
                var ProductName=AddProduct.get(results["ProductName"]);
                var ProductPrice=AddProduct.get(results["ProductPrice"]);
                var ProductQuantity=AddProduct.get(results["ProductQuantity"]);
                    console.log(results.ProductName);
                    console.log(results.ProductPrice);
                    console.log(results.ProductQuantity);

                }
                },
             error:function(error){
                 console.log("Error:"+error.message);
             }

});
```

output:

> 2
>
> CQh20U49jf
>
> undefined
>
> undefined
>
> undefined
>
> i5rtVQxich
>
> undefined
>
> undefined
>
> undefined

Comment: you are getting id from Object and try to read values from result..

Comment: [{"ProductName":"Motog","ProductPrice":13000,"ProductQuantity":10}]           this my json file i tried it already it is not working

Comment: Use this coding    console.log(results.ProductName); and console.log(results.ProductPrice); and console.log(results.ProductQuantity);

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
query.find({
            success:function(results)
            { 
            console.log(results.length);
            for(i=0;i<results.length;i++)
            {
              object=results[i];
            console.log(object.id);
            var ProductName=object.ProductName;
            var ProductPrice=object.ProductPrice;
            var ProductQuantity=object.ProductQuantity;
                console.log(ProductName);
                console.log(ProductPrice);
                console.log(ProductQuantity);
            }
            },
         error:function(error){
             console.log("Error:"+error.message);
         }
```

});

Comment: sorry boss not working it shows undefined. any way thank you for your response

Comment: @SrinivasAppQube made some changes..now give a try

Comment: query.get("36iUEFs7YL", {
  success: function(res) {
    var objectId=res.id;
     var productName=res.get("ProductName");
                var productPrice=res.get("ProductPrice");
                var productQuantity=res.get("ProductQuantity");
      console.log("Id is:"+objectId);
console.log("test1"+productName);
                    console.log("test2"+productPrice);
                    console.log("test3"+productQuantity);
  },
  error: function(object, error) {
console.log("ERROR::"+error.message);
                    
    }
});